# delay and struct handling when running loading map on selection of navigation drawer item

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer

I am doing an application in which i am having navigation drawer which are having some of option like search places which will load the map to search the places . i have don the functionality . my problem is when i select the option of navigation menu to load the map to search the places, the ui is struck-ing and it taking time to load the map. i need to solve this issue need to add the progress dialog in between the fragment and the navigation drawer to load the map , by means by taking the map object in the navigation drawer to see is the map is loaded or not then cancel the progress dialog . please help me to how to do it

Answer (score 0):

just put map loading code in Handler Like:

```
new Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        // map loading code here 
    } 
}, 300);
```

it may help

Comment: Handler.postDelayed cannot be resolved to a type, error i am using it inside the fragment